# Отправить уведомление на Android смартфон

Tags: php, android

Здравствуйте, мне нужно узнать каким способом можно максимально эффективно отправить уведомление из PHP файла на Android телефон, т.е. принцип как в чате, но человек отправляет свою геопозицию PHP документу, он записывает координаты в БД и отправляет их мне на телефон, телефон получает координаты и тут же ставит маркер на карте, все реализовано но получать данные о геопозиции нужно самому, а делать ежесекундное обновление - некрасиво.
Как отправить геопозицию imidiately?

Comment: Используйте FirebaseCloudMessages